# Configuration of GNU Radio and UHD project with Qt Creator

Tags: qt, gnuradio, uhd

I'm currently implementing a GUI interface for a very small GNU Radio application. The application will simply connect to a USRP device, receive some IQ samples and forward them through a TCP socket. Following the gqrx project file example, I was able to run some example gnuradio blocks (the dial tone example from gr-analog). Problems started when I tried to include UHD/USRP blocks into the project. Basically, Qt creator report the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgnuradio-uhd.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::ALL_MBOARDS
```

The .pro file configured as shown below:

```
 QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = USRPDialog
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    usrpdialog.cpp

HEADERS  += \
    usrpdialog.h \
    ui_sdrdialog.h

FORMS += \
    sdrdialog.ui
CONFIG += c++11

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig

PKGCONFIG += gnuradio-analog \
             gnuradio-blocks \
             gnuradio-digital \
             gnuradio-filter \
             gnuradio-fft \
             gnuradio-runtime\
             gnuradio-uhd


LIBS += -lboost_system$$BOOST_SUFFIX -lboost_program_options$$BOOST_SUFFIX -lboost_thread$$BOOST_SUFFIX

LIBS += -luhd -lgnuradio-uhd
```

And this is the function that calls the uhd::usrp_source object

```
void USRPDialog::createFlowgraph()
{
    tb = gr::make_top_block("usrp");
    d_tcpSource = gr::blocks::tcp_server_sink::make(sizeof(gr_complex),"127.0.0.1",d_rxTCPPort,true);
    d_usrpSource = gr::uhd::usrp_source::make(uhd::device_addr_t(ipAddressLineEdit->text().toStdString()),
                                              uhd::stream_args_t("fc32"));
    //Connecting blocks
    tb->connect(d_usrpSource,0,d_tcpSource,0);
    tb->start();
}
```

UHD is installed in my system (GNU Radio flowgraphs in my system can connect to USRP devices without any problem). Could anyone shed some light as to why this problem occurs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

too late answer , but fo future ...

I recommend you that use this page step by step: [Build UHD from sources](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html)

and after these steps , you can use all methods classes and uhd API to build your project in C/C++.

> **note**:don't forget installing winusb for detect usrp devices.

you can use examples in dir: uhd/host/examples.

you can use simple example for finding (detecting usrp device) by name: uhd_find_devices.exe after building uhd , etc.